# Friendly URLs in Wordpress - I need to prepare a custom rule for products (.htaccess or PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, clean-urls

On my existing website product pages work like this:

https://example.com/product-page/?xsin=418ZU3QNA

I need urls to look like:

https://example.com/product-page/bla-bla-bla-seo-description-no-specified-length-used-as-product-description/418ZU3QNA

Quick facts:

I have a page created in wordpress, with slug=product-page, I'm passing a product id by `?xsin=418ZU3QNA`

Comment: What have you set your Settings > Permalinks too?

Comment: Is there a custom post type registered for products?

Comment: Here is my permalink setting:

https://example.com/2017/11/14/sample-post/

no, there is no custom post type registered for products

Comment: Any thoughts? I really need this problem solved